# Instance method not able to act on instance variable

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Even though I required `Nokogiri` and initialized the variable, my method does not have access to the Nokogiri methods. I want to do this:

```
class Requester

require 'nokogiri'

  def initialize(body)
    @body = body
  end

  def destination
    @body.at_css('destination')
  end
end
```

and then I pass `body`, which is a `Nokogiri` document.

```
mess = Requester.new(body)
```

When I do this I get a "No Method Error":

```
mess.destination
```

I don't understand. I thought my class would have all the Nokogiri methods if I `require` it.

The full error is on `at_css` and looks like:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `at_css' for #<Requester:0x007f685d971478>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? It raises No Method Error for `destination` or for `at_css`?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are confusing `require` and `include`.

`require` loads a file or a gem.

`include` includes the methods of another object.

`a.rb`:

```
module A
  def hello
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

`b.rb`:

```
require 'a'
class B
  include A
end

puts B.new.hello # hello world
```

However, you really need to rethink what you are trying to do. You can't include a class - you extend classes. And the object you are looking for is the class `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`.

If you are trying to build a document crawler you can use the delegator pattern:

```
require 'nokogiri'

class Requester < Delegator
  def initialize(body)
    super 
    @body = body
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
  end

  def __getobj__
    @doc
  end
end
```

Or you would create a subclass of `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`.

- http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html

Comment: How this answers the [well, not clearly stated] question?

Comment: Yea tried that.. But `include` wants a module, while `nokogiri` is a gem.. hmm do I put `nokogiri` in its own module? Seems hacky.. but what do I know?

Comment: I took the downvote back, because the stuff you have posted after my comment is related to the question.

Comment: @max that was it!!! I was doing this `include "nokogiri"` instead of this `include Nokogiri` that was my problem.. thanks for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: " you’d remove the misleading intro about includes and requires, which has in fact nothing to do with the question at all." @mudasobwa - read the OP's question. He is clearly using `require` believing that it will somehow bestow his class with the magic of nokogiri. So yes it is relevant.

Comment: OK, OK, sorry. You somehow gave a hint to the proper direction (I do not follow, especially taking into account that `includes A` in your code throws a parser error.) Anyway.